# creating a modal window in objective c for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, blocking

I have to create a static library for iphone which provides a interface Login. Login prompts a window and asks username and password.

I wanted to create a modal window. As the interface doesnt take any arguments. I have to create a independent window and put text boxes and login button on it.
Plz suggest me way to do this.

Thanks...

Comment: I have created a UIWindow and placed a login view controller on it. But the window in not modal. i.e. where login interface is called ,It is not waiting for user to input on it .it executes the code after login statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A flexible way to do this is to make the calling code pass in the parent view controller. Something like this would work:

```
[CustomLoginManagerClass shownLoginOver:self.viewController otherStuff:_____];
```

and then assuming your method definition is something like this, you can easily launch your modal from there.

```
+ (void)shownLoginOver:(UIViewController*)viewController otherStuff:(id)stuff
{
  [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Note that I have used a class method for this in my example. This is neater since all you are asking it to do is launch a modal from an existing view controller. This structure is used to good effect in DSActivityView (see: http://www.dejal.com/blog/development). This is a library for displaying modal loading screens over the top any other view.

Alternatively you may want to make it an instance method depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanx for the reply... But can you suggest some other way which does not require any parent view controller for displaying my Login view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You want a modal **view**. All `UIViewControllers` are able to present a modal view by using the following method:

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

Check the Apple reference guides for more information and samples.

Answer (score 1):

present it with:

```
  // to change the style of presentation
 viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle//....;
 //to change the transition
 viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle//...;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "modal window" playing games with the `NSRunLoop`, but I don't recommend it. It's very error prone and it's not the "Cocoa way".

I suggest you implement it the usual way, non modal with a delegate or block to inform the result.